# python socket doesn't work after restart application

Tags: python, sockets, py2exe

I have a python script server->client, and for some reasons i used py2exe to make an exe from py so i can use on machines without python installed.
And i have and update system:
I send command update to server and server start a bat file:

```
suprocess.Popen("C:/Server/server.bat", shell=False) #
```

and server.bat contains:

`@echo off
taskkill /f /im "dServer.exe"
echo D | xcopy /s /y \\netpath\share\Server\c:\Server
start dServer.exe
exit`
First time when i start dServer.exe it's working, i can send command from client to server and recieve answer. But after update and dServer.exe starts again, server will not work, i got socket.timeout error and can't send commands.
Does anybody know why it's not working second time?
p.s I have command : server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you give it enough time between the kill and restart? (on linux it can take tens of seconds between server instance ending without a clean socket shutdown until another server instance can register successfully for listening on the same socket parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that socket server doesn't close so quickly and second server start to fast and can't because port it's used.
I modified `dServer.py` and now before i call `server.bat` i close the socket.